# How Convert checkbox to switch toggle

Tags: php

I have a database in which one of the fields is a checkbox, which can have a value of 1 or 2. I want to convert this checkbox to a bootstrap switch toggle, but I couldn't reach that when switch change, the value on the field on the database change. I am using PHP and MySQL

This is my switch code:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

Answer (score -1):

For connecting to your database you'll want to do something like this in php:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

For getting the data from the database, you'll want to do something like this:

```
// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use database_name: ' . mysql_error());
}
//your select here
$qry = "SELECT * FROM [table_name]

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //this is where you set your key value
        $switchValue = $row["switch_name_in_db"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I'm not sure if 1 or 2 is considered checked or not but you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if($switchValue ==1){echo "checked";}?> data-toggle="toggle">
```

This will echo the worked "checked" if a key is set to 1

Comment: using this show the following error: Warning: Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmaker\ratesupdatesedit.php on line 258
data-toggle="toggle">

Comment: Yeah, 'Key' is just an example variable.  You will need to switch that out for the variable name you're using for the checkbox.

Comment: First thank, ok my I don't have a variable, my checkbox field is name UPDATED in MySQ,L now it is a checkbox in php, that I want is this checkbox show a bootstrap switch and the switch updated to 1 when switch is on. Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you are reading from the database to your PDF file?

Comment: PDF file? or php

Comment: Do you have a SELECT statement?  Should look like SELECT * FROM TABLE BLAH or something like that.

Comment: No I don't have, but for example if you have a form how do you update a value in MySQL with this switch?

Comment: What does your database schema, table, and columns look like.

Comment: Employee Name | Rate Start On |   Updated(this is the checkbox)
 Peter                 05/12/2019         Yes

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how a user may connect to a database, select a schema, select records from a table and set a key value.  You will need to change the variables/table names/ user name/password for it to work.

Comment: thanks, but maybe it is too much for me, I have all working you this checkbook that in want to replace for a toggle switch but it is just cosmetic, I was thinking was more simple just assign values and field to this toggle